# c# read-only field value can be change in console main method

Tags: c#, console-application

```
class Program
{
    private readonly static int[] dict = new int[9]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr1 = dict;
        arr1[2] = 10;
        var arr2 = dict;
    }
}
```

Execute the above code, arr1[2], arr2[2] and dict[2] all = 10, should dict[2] and arr2[2] still 3?

Comment: `readonly` does not mean "immutable". It just informs the compiler (and the JIT) that the field won't be reassigned after construction - not that the field is immutable.

Answer (score 3):

- `readonly` in C# means **only** that "this field can only be assigned in a constructor".
- It does **not** mean that a field's value is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so consider C#'s `readonly` to be equivalent to Java's `final` modifier on fields.
- While C++ and Swift have built-in support for immutable values, as of May 2020, C# does not (in C++ this is the `const` keyword, Swift uses `let` for similar purposes).
- Because C# and .NET do not support immutability, the only way to have an immutable value is by using a type that you *trust* to be immutable - or by exposing an object only via an `IReadOnly...` interface (though this still does not guarantee that the underlying value is immutable).

To change your code to make it immutable do this:

```
class Program
{
    private readonly static IReadOnlyList<Int32> numbers = new int[9]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr1 = dict;
        arr1[2] = 10; // <-- this will give you a compile-time error because `IReadOnlyList<T>` does not have a `set` indexer property.
        var arr2 = dict;
    }
}
```

---

#### Rant time:

Microsoft's design decisions for the CLR are interesting - the team can put Herculean effort into amazing features like Reified Generics and the ability to quickly verify that a CIL program is memory-safe - but compared to other languages and platforms available today the CLR is missing many features that I personally consider essential for writing modern, *safe*, software (though just because the CLR doesn't support a feature doesn't mean a language compiler can't have its own level of support - conversely the CLR supports some scenarios that the C# language doesn't support, such as tail-call optimization).

If the CLR has built-in support for immutability, then the runtime and JIT could optimize programs to run in NUMA (non-uniform memory access) systems by allowing immutable objects to be copied to multiple NUMA nodes - and even in typical desktop computing environments the JIT could take advantage of assertions of immutability when generating native machine code.

Because (as I understand) the CLR does not have built-in support for `const`-correctness it isn't possible for the CLR to *know* that a method in another library or assembly won't modify an object value (even if a method accepts an `IReadOnly...` interface, that method could still perform casts to other interfaces or types that do allow mutation).

Finally, because we're forced to use `IReadOnly...` interfaces for immutable objects it means that `struct` object-values have to be boxed (as interface method calls are virtual, unless it's inside an interface-constrained generic method) which introduces performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

Readonly does not mean you can´t **modify** the instance, but only you can´t **re-assign** it. So you can do this:

```
arr[0] = ...
```

but not this:

```
arr = new int[1];
```

Arrays are just objects. You can of course do anything on an object even it is `readonly`:

```
readonly MyClass m;
static void Main()
{
    m.MyProperty = 33;
}
```

Imagine further you´d have a `DoSomething`-method that modifies the objects state in some way:

```
class MyClass
{
    int MyProperty;
    void DoSomething() { this.MyProperty = 3; }
}
```

Now even if `m` was readonly within your first class, the same does not apply to the members within `MyClass`. Calling `DoSomething` will inherently change the instances state without the compiler having any chance to get noticude of that. You´d have to put `readonly`-modifier on all sub-sequent members as well to achieve real immutability.